Can I create high quality maps and 3D models using Dji Mini 3 (Pro)?
If possible I want to achieve the same level of precision as that from an more expensive drone with RTK (a few centimeters error), e.g. DJI Mavic 3 Enterprise.
From my understanding RTK consist of calculating atmospheric corrections from a base station and then transmitting the correction data to the GPS of the UAV in real time.
However it should be possible to achieve the same in postprocess (PPK)?
Alternatively I could perhaps use Ground Control Points?
If so I need to measure their position very precisely? What is the cheapest GPS I can use for this? Do I need something like this: SparkFun RTK Facet?
Still the cost of Dji Mini 3 + SparkFun RKT Facet << cost of DJI Mavic 3 Enterprise.
What software can I use for this?
